# How to parse a XML string as document object(DOM) in php

Tags: php, xml, dom, xml-parsing, domdocument

I want to parse a xml string into as XML document(DOM). I know how to do this when xml  is stored in  different file, example given at

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_dom.asp

```
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load(file.xml);
```

Now we can access the `$xmlDoc` as a  document object, and we can access and manipulate xml using DOM methods. But I want to parse a xml string as a document.I tried

```
$xmlstring = '
<users>
  <user>
    <name> nikhil </name>
    <password>1234 </password>
  </user>
  <user>
    <name>akhil </name>
    <password>123 </password> 
  </user>
</users>';
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load($xmlstring);
```

But this does not work, any ideas?

Comment: Instead of using `load()`, use the [`loadXML()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php) method.

Comment: @salathe It works, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [`DOMDocument::load`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.load.php) — Load XML from a file

As you can see in php manual, `load()` method only work for loading XML from a file.

If you want to load from string, use [`DOMDocument::loadXML`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php) that load XML from string.